# Erro install plugin with td-agent-gem

Tags: fluent

I`m install the plugin `td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-hipchat` and get:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  json (>= 1.4.3)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
   Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
```

Fluentd installed from the deb package, downloaded from the official site.

Environment

```
Ubuntu 14.10
td-agent 0.12.7
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gem 2.2.2
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I can install fluent-plugin-hipchat
`sudo /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-hipchat`

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, td-agent 0.12.7

Answer (score 1):

a)sudo /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-influxdb

OR

b)Use /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem

If you are using td-agent, please make sure to use td-agent's td-agent-gem command. td-agent has own Ruby so you should install gems into td-agent's Ruby, not other Ruby. Otherwise (e.g. you use the command belonging to system, rvm, etc.), you won't be able to find your "installed" plugins as they would be on your local installation of ruby but not in td-agent.